# Security Accessibility issue Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.InitializeLifetimeService()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz.NET is 2.2.3 in MVC3 application. Here's my code:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

   WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
   FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
   RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
   StartScheduler();
}

public static void StartScheduler()
{
   ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
   IScheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
   scheduler.Start();
   var jobDetail = new JobDetailImpl("General", null, typeof(Schedule));
   var trigger = new SimpleTriggerImpl("SampleTrigger",
       null,
       DateTime.UtcNow,
       null,
       SimpleTriggerImpl.RepeatIndefinitely,
       TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
       scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
}
```

During first run, I get following error:

```
Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.InitializeLifetimeService()'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.

Source=Quartz TypeName=Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.InitializeLifetimeService()
StackTrace:
at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.Instantiate()
at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.GetScheduler()
at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler()
```

But, when I request second time, then it runs properly. please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: @Charles sure, Thanks. Also please help me in my Question also.